# How to use a variable as an input into a Regex in order to search a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a variable that is in the format of \d\w\^\d\d\d\d^\w\w. What I am trying to do is pass the actual variable, in this case the hardcoded variable is 1B^1001^01, into a Regex so that I can parse through a string and pass a true value if it is found.

```
objPtFqr =  SIPE-NAE-001:SIPE-NAE-001/Programming.CommonPath.1B^1001^01.Code_Blue,object,JCI BV

roomNumber = 1B^1001^01 

codeType = Code_Blue
```

My code is not finding the variable within the string. Here is the method that uses the Regex.

```
public JciFqr ParseHL7Fqr(List<JciFqr> objPtFqrs, string roomNumber, string codeType)
{
List<JciFqr> folderParsedFQRs = new List<JciFqr>();
JciFqr parsedObjPtFqr = null;
Regex roomSearch = new Regex(@"""" + roomNumber + @"""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach (JciFqr objPtFqr in objPtFqrs)
{
    var result1 = roomSearch.Match(objPtFqr.ToString());

    if (result1.Success)
    {
        folderParsedFQRs.Add(objPtFqr);
    }
}

foreach (JciFqr folderParsedFQR in folderParsedFQRs)
{
    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(folderParsedFQR.ToString(), codeType, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        parsedObjPtFqr = folderParsedFQR; ;
    }
}
return parsedObjPtFqr;

}
}
}
```

Here is the delegate that calls the method:

```
var delegatedTask1 = Task.Run(async () =>
{
await objClient.OpenAsync(username, password, CancellationToken.None);
JciFqr objRootFqr = objClient.CreateFqr(siteDirector, path, JciFqr.Classifications.Folder, JciFqr.Types.Folder);
aobjRoomFqrs = await objClient.GetObjectsAsync(objRootFqr, CancellationToken.None);


foreach (JciFqr objFqr in aobjRoomFqrs)
{
    JciFqr objCodeBlueFqr = JciFqr.Create(objFqr, "Code_Blue", JciFqr.Classifications.Object, JciFqr.Types.BinaryValue);
    objPtFqrs.Add(objCodeBlueFqr);
}

parsedObjPtFqr = hl7Event.ParseHL7Fqr(objPtFqrs, roomNumber, codeType);
await objClient.WritePropertyAsync(parsedObjPtFqr, "Present Value", true ? "on" : "off", a_strPriority, CancellationToken.None);


});
```

Comment: What is  the value of `codeType`? It might also need `Regex.Escape`, as `roomNumber`.

Comment: @stribizhev added value of the strings to the Question above.

Comment: @Phil Since the string does not have double-quotes around the string you are searching, you need to remove quotes from the regex as well.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I got it. Since it was an object I needed to grab the individual Path string of the object (no way anyone but myself would have known this since it was a custom class). The Regex.Escape worked though once I pulled the right string out of the object. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the string is not found is that it has metacharacters in it. You can fix that by passing the string to [`Escape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) first:

```
Regex roomSearch = new Regex(Regex.Escape(roomNumber), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Comment: It's still not hitting on the Regex. added the values of the strings to the question above. –

Comment: It had to due with how my ToString method was creating the string. Once I pulled the individual path your suggestion around Regex.Escape worked. Thanks!